# Selenium in Python. When launching the test, a message about the auxiliary class pops up

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a problem with the helper class when running the test.
As it is only in the Contakt class:

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, firstname, middlename, lastname, nickname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.middlename = middlename
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.nickname = nickname
```

it's all ok and the test works. And how will I do it:

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, firstname, middlename, lastname, nickname, title_photo, email, email2, email3):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.middlename = middlename
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.title_photo = title_photo
        self.email = email
        self.email2 = email2
        self.email3 = email3
```

this test does not work in the console pops up such a message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi4FO.png)

I have added parameters for testing:

```
def test_add_contact_in_book_address(self):
        wd = self.wd
        self.open_home_page(wd)
        self.login(wd, username="admin", password="secret")
        self.user_data(wd, Contact(firstname="Lukasz", middlename="Ebi", lastname="Blaszkowski", nickname="lblaszkowski"))
        self.adding_a_picture_and_name(wd, Contact(title_photo="Chomik"))
        self.e_mail_data(wd, Contact(email="janekkolasa@wp.pl", email2="janekkolasa2@wp.pl", email3="janekkolasa3@wp.pl"))
```

Comment: The init method for the class `Contact` 8 arguments. `firstname, middlename, lastname, nickname, title_photo, email, email2, email3`. While creating a Contact object inside your `test_add_contact_in_book_address` method you have passed just 4 out of these 8 arguments which is what the error message is complaining about in your screenshot

Comment: You can leverage the use of default arguments if you don't always want to pass all 8 of them while creating the Contact Object. Something like `def __init__(self, firstname, middlename, lastname, nickname, title_photo=None, email=None, email2=None, email3=None):`. Please note that you can have any other string as the default value for your optional arguments

Comment: @DebanjanB : I am sure that a "dangling" webdriver session does not raise a `TypeError` Exception.

Comment: @GPT14 You are right, I have overlooked the question description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how to make classe contact pass all parameters to:

def test_add_contact_in_book_address(self):

```
    self.user_data(wd, Contact(firstname="Lukasz", middlename="Ebi", lastname="Blaszkowski", nickname="lblaszkowski"))
    self.adding_a_picture_and_name(wd, Contact(title_photo="Chomik"))
    self.e_mail_data(wd, Contact(email="janekkolasa@wp.pl", email2="janekkolasa2@wp.pl", email3="janekkolasa3@wp.pl"))
```

because now there are 4 out of 8.